# geometry node-adjust radius of cylinder to scale with a cube for halfpipe

Tags: node-editor, transforms, geometry

This is difficult to explain, likely to do with the way i went about my project and im not very good with math. I created a procedural halpipe skate ramp with geometry nodes. I used a cylinder to boolean a cube so the center of the ramp would be at 0 on x axis so i could mirror it. im posting a video of the problem which is at 25 seconds in. (EDIT I have a transform node before the boolean happens. If i adjust the x  scale it works beautifully, so i use a seperate xyz and combine xyz to extract that axis, except it gets all wonky. I tried using a scale vector to that axis and the same issue. it seems to only work when i adjust the parameter of the transform node itself.) I tried all sorts of pi *2 * radius type math to no avail. Perhaps someone could help, or suggest a better way to go about it. I was close on another attempt using curves and raycast nodes, but scrapped it due to my lack of organization and getting the lost in the tree. I have other minor problems to fix with the railing as you'll see, but thats no biggie.
https://youtu.be/FRELdOJBKbU
thanks in advance.
the actual problem https://youtu.be/lJ1FJrJfFPk

Comment: If it's not the railing, what _is_ the problem at 25s? How would you like the shape to behave?

Comment: I need to edit my original question .So i have a transform node before the boolean happens. If i adjust the x  scale it works beautifully, so i use a seperate and combine to extract that axis, except it gets  all wonky. I tried using a scale vector to that axis and the same issue. it seems to only work when i adjust the parameter of the transform node itself.

Comment: I still don't get it.. sorry.. do you want the arc always to be circular, never elliptical? Is that it? A sketch of the desired behaviour would help.

Comment: sorry, should have done that in the first place <https://youtu.be/lJ1FJrJfFPk> it works the way i want in the beginning. but i have two of these that i would like to control from the panel together